# Syntax error in 'from flask import Flask'

Tags: python, flask

After installing Flask, When I used

`from flask import Flask`

to check if flask is properly installed or not, it gave the following error

```
>>> from flask import Flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 151
    server: "BaseWSGIServer"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: @Carcigenicate based on their callstack looks like python 3.5

Comment: @CoryKramer Ah, yes, you're right. I'm not sure what exact version introduced annotations in that context. Annotations have been available for things like function parameters since 3.0 afaik, but class attribute annotations may not have become available until later versions.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is now at 2.0.0, which has ratcheted forward on requirements.

If you're on a system that is still on Python3.5, your alternative is to install the most recent in the 1.x line, and put

```
Flask==1.1.4
```

in your `requirements.txt`, or

```
venv/bin/pip install Flask==1.1.4
```

to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you're running Python 3.5. Variable annotations that the library is attempting to use weren't [introduced until 3.6 though](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations).

Upgrade to at least 3.6 to solve this. 3.9 is available too, so unless you need to use an older version for some reason, you might as well just to a full upgrade of your version.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is now at 2.0.0, and has ratcheted forward on requirements.

If you're on a system that is still on Python3.5, you are out of luck for 2.0.0. Your alternative is to install the most recent in the 1.x line.

Specify

```
Flask==1.4.4
```

if you're using `requirements.txt`, or

```
venv/bin/pip install Flask==1.1.4
```

to install it manually.